# php replacing between two tags in file html

Tags: php, html

I have a file.html with text like this

```
<h1 id="content1">Hello!</h1>
```

I have a form like this

```
<form method="POST"><textarea name="content1"></textarea></form>
```

and confirm button below this.
What i need is to replace text between tags in html file with text in form.
The code i've already got:

```
<? if ( isset ($_POST['submit']) ) 
{
$handle = fopen("file.html", "c+");
if ($handle)
 {
 if (isset($_POST['content1'])
 {
   stream_get_line($handle, 4096, '"content1">');
   $stringtoreplace = stream_get_line($handle, 4096, '</h1>');
   *INSERT REPLACEMENT CODE HERE*
 }
 fclose($handle);
 }
}
?>
```

Help with it please...

---

Got it! Thank you all for answers. There is working code:

```
<?if ( isset ($_POST['submit']) ) 
{
$handle = fopen("file.html", "c+");
if ($handle)
 if ( isset ($_POST['content1']) ) 
 {
 stream_get_line($handle, 4096, '"content1">');
 $stringtoreplace=stream_get_line($handle, 4096, '</h1>');
 fclose($handle); //getting string between <h1 id="content1"> and </h1>
 $file = 'file.html';
 $contents = file_get_contents($file);
 $contents = str_replace($stringtoreplace,$_POST['content1'],$contents);
 file_put_contents($file,$contents); //rewriting file with new string
 }
}
?>
```

Comment: Can be a find replace?

Comment: can you use javascript 'innerhtml'?  Set the new code as a PHP var $innerhtml then if $innerhtml is set you have the js function replace html content.

Comment: i need to replace code in html, that included in php. im doing some kind of cms for 1+ simple page and admin should be able to change text using form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me, this seems good:

```
<?php if ( isset ($_POST) ) 
{
    $find = $_POST['find'];
    $replace = $_POST['replace'];
    $file = 'test.txt';
    $contents = file_get_contents($file);
    $contents = str_replace($find,$replace,$contents);
    file_put_contents($file,$contents);
}
?>

<form method="POST" action="index.php">
    <input name="find" placeholder="Path to find" value="">
    <input name="replace" placeholder="Path to replace" value="">
    <input type="submit" value="Go">
</form>
```

I hope that it works to you.

Comment: It made me understand how to rewrite file properly, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

why don't you use PHP instead a simple html file?

```
//file.php
<h1 id="content1"><?php echo $content1 ?></h1>

//main.php
<?php
if (isset($_POST['content1']) {
  $content1 = $_POST['content1'];
  include 'file.php';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use simply `str_replace` from php.

```
 if (isset($_POST['content1'])
 {
   stream_get_line($handle, 4096, '"content1">');
   $stringtoreplace = stream_get_line($handle, 4096, '</h1>');
   $string = str_replace($stringtoreplace, $_POST['content1'], fread($link, filesize('file.html')));
 }
```

Comment: The problem here is that is not the only string in whole file. There are some more strings coming before and after... Will it work?

Comment: Yes it will, @Nalmelune

Comment: Your answer helped me. Thank you. :) Sorry, still can't upvote.